# Java volatile custom object - Full/Deep object visibility

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

I have the following:

```
public class MainClass {
    private final Map<Integer, List<MyCustomObject>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized addMyCustomObject(MyCustomObject customObj) {
        List<MyCustomObject> customObjList = myMap.get(customObj.getId());

        if (customObjList == null) {
            customObjList = new LinkedList<>();
        }
        customObjList.add(customObj);
    }

    public synchronized List<MyCustomObject> getList(int customObjId) {
        return myMap.get(customObjId);
    }
}

public class MyCustomObject {
    private volatile MyCustomObject sonCustomObject;
    private volatile int id;

    public MyCustomObject(MyCustomObject sonCustomObject, int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sonCustomObject = sonCustomObject;
    }

    public void changeId(int newId) {
        this.id = newId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void changeSon(MyCustomObject sonCustomObject) {
        this.sonCustomObject.setId(-1);
        this.sonCustomObject = sonCustomObject;
        this.sonCustomObject.setId(this.id);
    }
}
```

My questions are the following:

1. What happens if, given a MyCustomObject, its ID is changed? is this change visible to other threads? (No synchronization) I Think yes, ID is int and changes its reference.
2. What happens if, given a MyCustomObject, its SON'S id is changed? is this change reflected to other threads? (No synchronization) I think yes, for the previous reason
3. What happens if, given a MyCustomObject **without volatile** keyword on its SON field, the ID value of the son is changed? Is this change reflected to other threads? I think yes, because id is int and changes its reference.

**RULE OF THUMB:**
Let's assume the following rule of thumb: If a complex object is shared, it should be synchronized when mutual exclusion is needed, but synchronization must occur also for those fields which do not change their reference (i.e. complex objects instead of primitives like int or String). This is needed because using synchronization, all the updates are granted to be shared safely by java memory model.

Thanks

Comment: Volatile `myList` does essentially nothing here, as you are not reassigning the list, and the volatility applies *only* to the list reference, not the structure or contents of the list: you may as well make it final.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, so i'm actually not refreshing correctly my shared object. I guess that simply reassigning the same object without further isntantiation is not enough, right?

Comment: @AndyTurner I have updated my code, the reference of "myMap" is never changed but its inner content does, will it be visible to all threads?

Comment: no, neither `HashMap` nor `LinkedList` are safe without external synchronization, as described in their Javadoc.

Comment: So this means that without explicit synchronization i will never have updated values in all threads, right? So volatile keyword is useless if i i know that my reference will not change in time. So let's assume that i already have a MyCustomObject instance and I want to change the ID of it after it has already been added to the map (making the add method synchronized). My changes will not be reflected until i put this change in a synchronized block, right? My ID is volatile though and it changes its reference, so maybe in this case is not needed to synchronize, right?

Comment: I changed my question, maybe it can help to understand my doubts

Comment: Yes it would not be visible to other thread that has a reference to the map. Only when the the id is read will it be visible. Good for understanding but do not code like that! It would not be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question: can I use volatile to have the latest updates of the map?

I hope I understood it correctly.

*Imagine if `Thread B` executes `MyCustomObject()` constructor:*
That will enable this `MyCustomObject` to be made available to other threads (only when they encounter and **read** the volatile id). (recommend that setting the id is the last statement in the constructor). However there could be many such objects with the same id as per the code sample given.

*Imagine if `thread A` executes `addMyCustomObject()`:*
Thread A will get the latest updates including the properly constructed `MyCustomObject` instance.

*Imagine if `thread C` executes `getList()`:*
It might or might not return the right result. The map is final so it has the properly published state of it at the time it was constructed. However **it is a mutable holder and therein lies the problem.** You would need to have synchronization here.

*Could you make the map volatile as well?*
Yes you could but what would that achieve. One would go mad trying to figure out the thread related issues in such an implementation.

**Why is such coding not recommended?**
The above code is not clear to read and follow in terms of concurrent environments. It is fragile. Recommendation is to use synchronization constructs to clarify mutual exclusion and visibility. Volatile has its uses such as flags.

*Note: Volatile is for guaranteeing visibility and locking/synchronization is for both visibility and atomicity.*

Please let me know in case of a fallacy in my explanation.

**Edit 1: Answer to your updated questions:**

*Q1: What happens if, given a MyCustomObject, its ID is changed? is this change visible to other threads? (No synchronization) I Think yes, ID is int and changes its reference.*

A1: Not till the id is referenced by the calling thread.

*Q2: What happens if, given a MyCustomObject, its SON'S id is changed? is this change reflected to other threads? (No synchronization) I think yes, for the previous reason*

A2: Same as above.

*Q3: What happens if, given a MyCustomObject without volatile keyword on its SON field, the ID value of the son is changed? Is this change reflected to other threads? I think yes, because id is int and changes its reference.*

A3: Again only when the volatile is read. Of course one could call `changeSon()` again and again and the other thread would not see the updated SON.

The best approach would be to create a multithreaded test harness and run the test cases some N times. I am assuming you have a multicore system. Try not to use a VM that is assigned a single core.

Comment: Hi Khanna, thanks for your answer!
I understand the needing of synchronization in this example, that's why I updated my question explaining my doubts more clearly. Since the map is mutable, its content should be synchronized. But should synchronization occur even when managing already retrieved MyCustomObject instances? If you can check my updated question maybe it can be clearer for you to understand what are my doubts. Do you think that my RULE OF THUMB point is correct? Thanks!

Comment: If the contents of the final map do not change then everything is visible and all goes well. If the contents are mutable then all such guarantees are off.

Comment: But if a single MyCustomObject changes its state i have to apply synchronization, is it right? Since the point here is not the mutual exclusion, would you advise to use synchronization for every MyCustomObject change or just for its complex inner fields? For example, I think that changing a MyCustomObject ID makes the new ID visible to other threads WITHOUT synchronization, because ID is primitive and volatile. But synchronization is needed when changing values,like complex objects and not primitive types, without changing their reference. Is this true? Thanks

Comment: As mentioned: Volatile is for guaranteeing visibility and locking/synchronization is for both visibility and atomicity.
One could fine grain the locking and volatile and it may even work! But the result would be a quagmire - difficult to follow through. Recommendation is to limit volatile. See: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp06197/index.html

Comment: Yes the updated id is visible when it is read. However the map would not have this updated id as the key.

Comment: I read the article you posted and the important part for me was: **Pattern #2: one-time safe publication**. Do you think that making the _initInBackground_ method synchronized, volatile keyword would have been useless?
Furthermore, You said: **the updated id is visible when it is read. However the map would not have this updated id as the key.**. So this means that if another thread has the direct same reference of my custom object it will get the latest value. But if it tries to get the object from another source (i.e. the map) the update is not visible even if the ID was volatile

Comment: If locked then visibility is guaranteed so you need not have volatile. If it gets the object based on the new id from the map, the map would not have the new id as the key.

Comment: Remember: Volatile is for guaranteeing visibility and locking/synchronization is for both visibility and atomicity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212983/discussion-between-lazarus-and-khanna111).